# C++ template function implementation is not correct

Tags: c++, function, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I've implemented this function here (in a single header file).

```
//header.h
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <type_traits>



   template < typename T,
           typename = std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T> >::type >
void f(T t) {
    printf("Integer function\n");
}

template void f(int i);
```

The main is below...

```
#include "header.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int p = 3;
    f(p);
}
```

It compiles... no problem, but it doesn't show the content of the printf, what am i missing?...
(i'm using eclipse as IDE, it could be a problem?)

One more thing... does it make sense this implementation? (i would like to write different code based on the type in input, whether it is unsigned or not).

```
template < typename T,
           typename = std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>,
           typename = std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>
>
void f(T t) {
    printf("Unsigned f version.\n");
}

template < typename T,
           typename = std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>,
           typename = std::enable_if<std::is_signed<T>::value>
>
void f(T t) {
    printf("Signed f version.\n");
}
```

In this case it doesn't compile... so how to deal with this?

Thank you

Update...

I tried the modification suggested in the first code, it gives me the following error

```
..\header.h:19:58: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<bool <anonymous>, class _Tp> struct std::enable_if'
            typename = std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T> >::type >
                                                          ^
..\header.h:19:58: error:   expected a constant of type 'bool', got 'std::is_integral<_Tp>'
..\header.h:19:61: error: expected '>' before 'type'
            typename = std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T> >::type >
                                                             ^
..\main.cc: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
```

Update 2...

Ok guys... I've been trying to figure out what it is i do not understand... so i'm digging into the code of type_traits (so my goal is to understand what i've done wrong...)

I report the code for the enable_if (from type_traits).

```
template<bool, typename _Tp = void>
    struct enable_if //Lukkio decl. 1
    { };

  // Partial specialization for true.
  template<typename _Tp>
    struct enable_if<true, _Tp> //Lukkio decl. 2
    { typedef _Tp type; };
```

Because i want to understand what happens to a line like:

```
template<
    typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>
>
void function(T t) {
    printf("Is integral!\n");
}
```

So assuming `T` is fixed (let's say int, which is integrale) the `std::enable_if::value>` use the decl. 1, assuming however the `_Tp` is of type `void` so actually what happens, in terms of reduction (i now substitute to `T` the keyword `int`... should be something like

```
template<
        typename int,
        typename = std::enable_if<std::is_integral<int>::value>
    >
```

namely

```
template<
        typename int,
        typename = std::enable_if<1>
    >
```

So my question is... what does the second typename stands for?

Comment: `std::enable_if_t` or `std::enable_if<..>::type`

Comment: Thanks for answer @Columbo , what is the difference?

Comment: Why declaring `template void f(int i);` in `header.h` ?

Comment: @Lukkio One makes sense and the other doesn't. One works and the other doesn't. ...

Comment: Just copied and pasted from the web... no particular reason.

Comment: @Columbo why it does make sense? where's the problem? the logic beyond the change i mean. Does your template make some particular check that mine doesn't or whatsoever?

Comment: @Lukkio without the `::type` the anonymous template parameter is just defaulted to some instantiation of `std::enable_if`, rather than applying SFINAE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFINAE on default function template arguments doesn't really scale. You can only use this if you want to restrict a single overload to a particular class of types.

For non-overlapping multiple overloads (like your signed/unsigned integrals), you can SFINAE on the return type like this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

template < typename T>
auto f(T t) 
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<T>::value && std::is_integral<T>::value>
{
    printf("Unsigned f version.\n");
}

template < typename T>
auto f(T t) 
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<T>::value && std::is_integral<T>::value>
{
    printf("Signed f version.\n");
}

int main()
{
    unsigned u = 1;
    signed s = 1;
    f(u);
    f(s);
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dde4730142087cef)

**Note**: the `enable_if_t<T>` is a type alias for `typename enable_if<T>::type` that came available in C++14 (you can write it yourself)

Comment: Any reason you include `void` at the end? Just to be explicit about the return type?

Comment: @TartanLlama right, defaults to `void` anyway, but if `f(T)` would have to return `int` then you'd have to be explicit. thanks.

Comment: This syntax with the arrow... it is the first time i see it. I try anyway.

Comment: @Lukkio it's the C++11 trailing return type

Answer (score 2):

> In this case it doesn't compile... so how to deal with this?

Consider your templates again:

```
template < typename T,
           typename = std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>,
           typename = std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>
>
void f(T t) {
```

You're not actually using SFINAE. Your unnamed types are just `std::enable_if<X>`. That is always a valid type. In order for SFINAE to apply, you actually need to add `::type` at the end or use `std::enable_if_t`, that is:

```
template < typename T,
           typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>,
           typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>
>
void f(T t) {
```

Now, you'd run into two ambiguous function templates, which you can disambiguate by using the `enable_if_t` as a *value* instead of a type. That is:

```
template < typename T,
           std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value &&
                            std::is_unsigned<T>::value>* = nullptr
           >
void f(T t) { ... }
```

And similarly for the other case.

Comment: ah nice, never tried that one before, same default value, upvoted

Comment: It's complicated... never used this stuff before... is there i don't know... a kind of reference that explain how to use this new C++ feature (new for me of course...)? I thought it was more straight to apply.

Comment: @Lukkio Just browse through a bunch of questions on SO :)

Comment: @Barry I would prefer a paper, o whatever explaining the basic of the all these kind of construction... i know basic stuff about template and the reasoning you're making to implement what i was trying to do is struggling me... i would prefer a systematic way to learn the basic actually...

Comment: I've just found a draft of the standard... i'll have a look!

Comment: @Lukkio I'm not sure anybody has ever learned C++ by reading the standard.

Comment: I think I learned a lot about templates by answering questions on SO incorrectly and having people tell me why I'm an idiot. YMMV

Comment: Basically is what happen to me every day with VHDL... for basic question about template should i open another thread?

Comment: @Lukkio Yes. One question per question.